# Filtering from todays date, showing past dates

Tags: sorting, filter, powerapps-canvas

I followed advice on how to filter CDS records based on dates. I thought it was working last week, but now it's showing past dates. I am using powerapps and datasource is cds and I placing this into a gallery.

The formula which have been entered into the items field:

```
Sort(FirstN(Filter('Course schedule',End <= DateAdd(Today(), 70)),2),End)
```

Right now it's showing a record where End = 26/11. A past date. Plus a date in January 2022. However I have several dates between today and January. **The expected view would be to see the 2 upcoming records that are closest to today's date. And not past dates...**
[image]
*In this picture we see the End-field showing 26th of november and January 21st.*

The first is to understand why it's showing a past date and how to remedy it.
The second, what to add to sort it by end-date.

For clarification, 'Course schedule' is the table/entity I am referring to, End is the column/field inside of it that's chosen to filter from. It's a date type field.

Many thanks!

Comment: I now tried SortByColumns('Course schedule', End, Ascending) and it doesn't show any results at all, but no errors. I have 11 records in this table so it's not big.

Comment: I now added Ascending to it but it still is showing past dates: FirstN(Sort(Filter('Course schedule', End <= DateAdd(Today(), 70)), End, Ascending), 2)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I have figured it out just by trying. Not sure why though:

````
    Sort(
        Filter(
            'Course schedule',
            End >= DateAdd(
                Today(),
                1
            )
        ),
        End,
        Ascending
    ),
    2
)```
````